# Angular 11 Error trying to diff observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, signalr, observable

I have a SignalR service I'm subscribed to, I'd like to display the ticker pushes as a Clarity data grid.

Here is my event from SignalR:

```js
export interface TickerMessage {
  type: string;
  tradeId: number;
  sequence: number;
  time: Date;
  productId: number;
  price: number;
  side: string;
  lastSize: number;
  bestBid: number;
  bestAsk: number;
}
```

Here is my service:

```js
  constructor() {
    this.retries = 3;
    this.hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/stream/ticker')
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
  }

  public async load() {
    await this hub.start();
  }

  public getMessagesAsObservable(): Observable<TickerMessage[]> {
    let subj = new Subject<TickerMessage[]>();
    this.hub.stream<TickerMessage[]>(this.tickFuncName).subscribe(subj);
    return subj.asObservable();
  }
```

Here is my store:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TickerStore {
  private _ticker: BehaviorSubject<Array<TickerMessage>> = new BehaviorSubject<TickerMessage[]>([]);
  private _tickerSvc: TickerService;

  constructor() {
    this._tickerSvc = new TickerService();
    this._ticker.asObservable();
  }

  public async load() {
    await this._tickerSvc.load();
    this._tickerSvc.getMessagesAsObservable().subscribe(res => {
      this._ticker.next(res);
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log('error retrieving ticker feed: ' + err);
    });
  }

  get ticks() {
    return this._ticker.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Here is my component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticker',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css'],
  providers: [TickerService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  productMap: IProductTypeMap = ProductMap;
  productOrderSide: IProductTypeMap = ProductOrderSide;
  btcMarketFilter = new BtcMarketFilterComponent();
  feed: TickerMessage[];

  constructor(public tickerStore: TickerStore) {
    this.feed = [];
    this.tickerStore.load();
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.tickerStore.ticks.subscribe(res => {
      this.feed = res;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
}
```

Here is my template:

```html
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let m of tickerStore.ticks | async">
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.time | date:'longTime'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.sequence}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.tradeId}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{productMap[m.productId]}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.price | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{productOrderSide[m.side]}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.lastSize}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestBid | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestAsk | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

I've tried `tickerStore.ticks` to an array in the component, and then subscribing the array, but that doesn't seem to work. How do I create an observable array from a stream of messages so I can create a ticker feed?

Comment: In your component, you use `await` on a subscription object, does that do anything? Subscriptions aren't asynchronous. Also, in `getMessagesAsObservable()`, you can just use the `share()` operator instead of creating an entire Subject in order to multicast (I'm assuming that's why you're using a Subject at all).

Comment: I think I had await on my subscription object as a habit (I'm C# dev by default), the IDE said it didn't do anything, so I removed it. Is the share operator an optimization of what I have?

Answer (score 0):

```
<clr-dg-row *ngFor="let m of tickerStore.ticks | json | async">
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.time | date:'longTime'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.sequence}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.tradeId}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{productMap[m.productId]}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.price | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{productOrderSide[m.side]}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.lastSize}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestBid | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
  <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestAsk | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
</clr-dg-row>
```

try this it may helps you (json pipe)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problems, and there were many. Firstly, I needed to convert my `TickerService` to implement `IStreamSubscriber<TickerMessage>`. That made me implement the methods I needed so I could subscribe an instance of the class to the SignalR stream. Once I did that, I was able to hook up the `TickerService.next()` functionality to my `Subject<Array<TickerMessage>>`, instead of an Observable. Once I had the Subject hooked up, then the rest started working.

Serivce:

```js
export class TickerService implements IStreamSubscriber<TickerMessage> {

  connectionEstablished = false;
  retries: number;
  tickSource: Subject<Array<TickerMessage>>;
  private hub: HubConnection;
  private maxSize = 500;
  private readonly ticks: TickerMessage[];
  private readonly tickFuncName: string = 'StreamTicks';

  constructor() {
    // build the hub.
    this.retries = 3;
    this.hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/stream/ticker')
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    // build/populate the ticker
    console.log('attempting to load existing ticker feed');
    const ticks = sessionStorage.getItem('tickerFeed');
    if (typeof ticks != 'undefined' && ticks) {
      this.ticks = JSON.parse(ticks);
    } else {
      console.log('existing ticker feed does not exist, will populate');
      this.ticks = [];
    }

    // build the ticker source.
    this.tickSource = new Subject<Array<TickerMessage>>();
  }

  public async load() {
    await this.hub
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`SignalR connection success! connectionId: ${this.hub.connectionId} `);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`SignalR connection error: ${error}`);
      }).finally(() => {
        this.connectionEstablished = true;
        console.log(`connected to ${this.hub.baseUrl}`);
      });
    this.hub.stream<TickerMessage>(this.tickFuncName).subscribe(this);
  }

  public complete(): void {
    console.log('ticker streaming complete');
  }

  public error(err: any): void {
    console.log('error streaming from server: ' + err);
  }

  public next(value: TickerMessage): void {
    if (this.ticks.length === this.maxSize) {
      this.ticks.pop();
      this.ticks.unshift(value);
    } else {
      this.ticks.unshift(value);
    }

    this.tickSource.next(this.ticks);
    sessionStorage.setItem('tickerFeed', JSON.stringify(this.ticks));
  }
}
```

Store:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TickerStore {
  ticks$: Subject<Array<TickerMessage>>;
  private _tickerSvc: TickerService;

  constructor() {
    this._tickerSvc = new TickerService();
    this.ticks$ = this._tickerSvc.tickSource;
  }

  public async load() {
    await this._tickerSvc.load();
  }
}
```

Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticker',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css'],
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {

  productMap: IProductTypeMap = ProductMap;
  productOrderSide: IProductTypeMap = ProductOrderSide;
  btcMarketFilter = new BtcMarketFilterComponent();
  tickerStore: TickerStore;

  constructor(public tStore: TickerStore) {
    this.tickerStore = tStore;
  }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.tickerStore.load();
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<ng-container id="allFeedTable" class="limit-height" *ngIf="(tickerStore.ticks$ | async)?.length; else loading">
  <clr-datagrid class="table table-noborder datagrid-compact">
    <clr-dg-column>Time</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Sequence</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Trade ID</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Market</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Price</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Side</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Last Size</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Best Bid</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Best Ask</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let m of tickerStore.ticks$ | async">
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.time | date:'longTime'}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.sequence}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.tradeId}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{productMap[m.productId]}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.price | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{productOrderSide[m.side]}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.lastSize}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestBid | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{m.bestAsk | currency:'USD'}}</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
    <clr-dg-footer>
      <clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgPageSize]="25">
        <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[25,50,100,250,500]">Updates per page</clr-dg-page-size>
        {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}} of {{pagination.totalItems}} updates
      </clr-dg-pagination>
    </clr-dg-footer>
  </clr-datagrid>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
    <span class="spinner spinner-inverse">
      Loading...
    </span>
</ng-template>
```